# (for) any longer

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is 'for' necessary before 'any longer', or at all?

I won't be able to talk (for) any longer.
I can't talk (for) any longer.
I can't workout (for) any longer.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the intended meaning of these sentences, for is not required in these sentences.

In your example, "I won't be able to talk any longer" the words "talk any longer" is what you won't be able to do. There is no need to have a *for* in the sentence as the meaning is clear without it.

For is a word that can be used in many ways. In [Mirriam Webster's online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for) we see that one of the meanings of for is listed as:

> **9** -- used as a function word to indicate duration of time or extent of space

In your example sentences, the prase 'any longer' does not require the use of the word for as it is *not* indicating a duration in time, even though it may appear to be. Instead it is indicating the cessation (stopping) of the activity.

You would need to use for in these alternative sentences, which do refer to a duration of time:

"I won't be able to talk ***for*** two days after the operation."

"I can't talk ***for*** longer than 20 minutes."

"I can't workout for more than 30 minutes."